# Выпадающее меню на CSS3

Tags: css, css3

Стараюсь создать выпадающее меню средствами CSS но подпункты в браузере не отображаются. Вижу только горизонтальное меню.

```css
#content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 800px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: gray;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 850px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: gray;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  /*rgb(0, 129, 20);  */
}

#nav:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  height: 50px;
}

#nav ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

#nav ul li a {
  color: rgb(0, 205, 0);
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
}

#nav .down {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  background: #575757;
  display: none;
}

#nav .down li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
}

#nav li:hover .down {
  display: block;
}

#nav .down li a {
  line-height: 45px;
  height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">Main</a>
      <ul class="down">
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="content">
  <br />
  <form action="goods.php" method="post">
    good's name<br /><br />
    <input type="text" name="goods" <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="btn_select" value="select">
    <input type="submit" name="btn_insert" value="insert">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

**UPDATE:** Исправил код. Добавил z-index и субменю появилось но сейчас если медленно наведу курсор на субменю оно исчезает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Для этого нам нужно провести что то типа проверки и делаем так :**

```css
#content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 800px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: gray;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 850px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: gray;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  /*rgb(0, 129, 20);  */
}

#nav:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  height: 50px;
}

#nav ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

#nav ul li a {
  color: rgb(0, 205, 0);
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
}

#nav .down {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  background: #575757;
  display: non;
  border:1px solid red;
}

#nav .down li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
}

#nav li:hover .down {
  display: block;
}

#nav .down li a {
  line-height: 45px;
  height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">Main</a>
      <ul class="down">
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="content">
  <br />
  <form action="goods.php" method="post">
    good's name<br /><br />
    <input type="text" name="goods" <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="btn_select" value="select">
    <input type="submit" name="btn_insert" value="insert">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

после чего видим что пункты меню расположены вне родителя, делаем вывод что у нас что то не так , смотрим что родительские пункты имеют `float` и мы для наших пунктов вложенного меню должны очистить обтекание т.е сделать `float:none;`

**после этого код становится такой**

```css
#content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 800px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: gray;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 850px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: gray;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  /*rgb(0, 129, 20);  */
}

#nav:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  height: 50px;
}

#nav ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

#nav ul li a {
  color: rgb(0, 205, 0);
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
}

#nav .down {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  background: #575757;
  display: non;
  z-index: 100;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: none;
}

#nav .down li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
}

#nav li:hover .down {
  display: block;
}

#nav .down li a {
  line-height: 45px;
  height: 45px;
}

<nav id="nav
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">Main</a>
      <ul class="down">
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="content">
  <br />
  <form action="goods.php" method="post">
    good's name<br /><br />
    <input type="text" name="goods" <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="btn_select" value="select">
    <input type="submit" name="btn_insert" value="insert">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

после этих манипуляций мы видим пункты скрытого меню в составе выпадающего и теперь вернём на место `display:none;` проверяем и видим что меню появляется но не возможно провести `click` по ссылкам : это означает что оно слишком низко расположено, действие `hover` пропадает и исправляем `css` нашего выпадающего меню придаём (для видимости нашим `li` **background**)и видим опять отступ и добавляем в начало css это

`*{margin:0; padding:0;}`

и задаём пунктам меню высоту

`#nav ul li {height:100%;}`
на выходе получаем готовое меню с выпадающим списком без косяков

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 800px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: gray;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 850px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: gray;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  /*rgb(0, 129, 20);  */
}

#nav:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  height: 50px;
}

#nav ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 10;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

#nav ul li a {
  color: rgb(0, 205, 0);
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
}

#nav .down {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  background: #cc0000;
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
  float: none;
}

#nav .down li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
}

#nav li:hover .down {
  display: block;
}

#nav .down li a {
  line-height: 45px;
  height: 45px;
}

<nav id="nav
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">Main</a>
      <ul class="down">
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="content">
  <br />
  <form action="goods.php" method="post">
    good's name<br /><br />
    <input type="text" name="goods" <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="btn_select" value="select">
    <input type="submit" name="btn_insert" value="insert">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помогли!

Comment: @Delphi159 хотя щас уже 2018 год и использовать float для меню не требубется ...есть чище методы

Comment: Максим Ленский стаж работы с web всего 2 недели поэтому пока на таком уровне не разбираюсь. :) Пользуюсь w3schools.com, htmlbook.ru и youtube. везде используют float. Вы что имеете ввиду?

Comment: я щас в отпуске - если хочешь давай я покажу , но это будет в teamviewer ...или сам смотри что такое и как верстают в 2018 году

Comment: Максим Ленский, спасибо!  Буду разбираться.

Answer (score 2):

В таком случае вам поможет свойство [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/z-index), которое отвечает за перекрытие элементов у блоков с position: relative, absolute или fixed. 
См. стили к **#nav li:hover .down**.

```css
#content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 800px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: gray;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 850px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: gray;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  /*rgb(0, 129, 20);  */
}

#nav:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  height: 50px;
}

#nav ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

#nav ul li a {
  color: rgb(0, 205, 0);
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
}

#nav .down {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  background: #575757;
  display: none;
}

#nav .down li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
}

#nav li:hover .down {
  display: block;
  z-index: 400;
}

#nav .down li a {
  line-height: 45px;
  height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">Main</a>
      <ul class="down">
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="content">
  <br />
  <form action="goods.php" method="post">
    good's name<br /><br />
    <input type="text" name="goods" <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="btn_select" value="select">
    <input type="submit" name="btn_insert" value="insert">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: valya выпадающее меню появляется но исчезает при наведении курсора мыши на пункт вертикального меню.

Comment: Исправил код. Добавил z-index и субменю появилось но если медленно наведу курсор на субменю оно исчезает.

Comment: Самое простое решение этой проблемы — обнулить отступы у body c помощью margin: 0

Comment: Valya! Заработал.  большое спасибо!